# is there a way to get list of SQLite databases using Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

how to fetch list of databases in SQLite using python, I know ".databases" in SQLite console but how to do it with python?

Comment: SQLite doesn't have databases. Each file is "a database". Those contain tables.

Comment: I want list of database like in MySQL, for now in sqlite i am listing files in one directory as a list of database. is there any proper way?

Comment: You can pass the exact same query into Python as the console